# Unable to locate element: Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

[image]

I want to select the ***More Information*** link by clicking on it. I have tried everything I could but every time the error ***NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector"*** pops up.

At first, I thought maybe because I did not change the tabs properly that's why this error is showing. But, even after using ***window_handles*** still I cannot locate any element on this page.

Please **HELP**!

```
self.driver.window_handles
        base = self.driver.window_handles[0]        
        child = self.driver.window_handles[1]

        window_set = {self.driver.window_handles[0], self.driver.window_handles[1]}

for x in window_set:
        if(base != x):
            self.driver.switch_to.window(x)
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("mc-lnk-moreInfo").click()
```

Comment: Done editing...

Comment: Hopefully its not within the iframe element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below solution using contains and ID

**Xpath with contains**

```
 element= WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), 'More information')]')))

 self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

or

**Xpath with ID**

```
element= WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "//a[@id='mc-lnk-moreInfo']")))

 self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**Working Solution :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("your url")
childframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "mainFrame")))
driver.switch_to.frame(childframe)
element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mc-lnk-moreInfo")))
print element.text
element.click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I hope it's not inside the box iframe and you are on the correct window

Comment: can i check your url if possible ?

Comment: https://cognizant.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/default.do?service=1&siteurl=cognizant&nomenu=true&main_url=%2Fmc3300%2Fe.do%3Fsiteurl%3Dcognizant%26AT%3DMI%26EventID%3D270725713%26UID%3D0%26Host%3DQUhTSwAAAARsExqu4GgL-iYFJs5YOBbUxv56rraW_ehe3gViLOJBIM7lTHyyRf1MixLvuy6ek5e6t84DuoTBdGqYDUcpAjRF0%26FrameSet%3D2%26MTID%3Dm4acde4fdba72b7cff47412b5e9261a2a

Comment: I see that the element I'm seeking to click is inside a frame. The problem is this frame has no ID to it. I don't thing frames can be accessed by XPATH

Comment: you can do that with frame index but if you check in your page multiple frames are present and also there are differnt approaches to identify frame like I did with NAME. would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer from your end.

Comment: in "your url" which url do I have to give?The childframe url or the parent url?

Comment: https://cognizant.webex.com/mw3300/mywebex/default.do?service=1&siteurl=cognizant&nomenu=true&main_url=%2Fmc3300%2Fe.do%3Fsiteurl%3Dcognizant%26AT%3DMI%26EventID%3D270725713%26UID%3D0%26Host%3DQUhTSwAAAARsExqu4GgL-iYFJs5YOBbUxv56rraW_ehe3gViLOJBIM7lTHyyRf1MixLvuy6ek5e6t84DuoTBdGqYDUcpAjRF0%26FrameSet%3D2%26MTID%3Dm4acde4fdba72b7cff47412b5e9261a2a

Answer (score 0):

*Try to [wait for the element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) then click on it*

*Replace*

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("mc-lnk-moreInfo").click()
```

*With following*

```
  self.more_info = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
        ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "//a[@id='mc-lnk-moreInfo']")))
    ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(self.more_info).click().perform()
```

---

*add the following on with your imports*

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
```

Comment: so, I should write this piece of code inside the for loop in my code?

Comment: also, I have already given a sleep(5) before this code. So I think that already makes the execution wait before the click happens

Comment: okay have you tried `find_element_by_id("//a[@id='mc-lnk-moreInfo']")`? I cant test with out live link, can you share the link?